# IndexError when using past_time_features with Autoformer in PyTorch

Tags: python-3.x

I'm working with the Autoformer model for time series forecasting using PyTorch, and I'm encountering an `IndexError` when I try to specify `past_time_features` as part of my input. The error message suggests an issue with tensor dimensions, specifically "too many indices for tensor of dimension 1". I'm not sure how to correctly shape my `past_time_features` to fit the model's requirements.
I want to know what is the batch["batch_time_features] and batch observed ..... .

```py
outputs = model(
    past_values=batch["past_values"],
    past_time_features=batch["past_time_features"],
    past_observed_mask=batch["past_observed_mask"],
    static_categorical_features=batch["static_categorical_features"],
    static_real_features=batch["static_real_features"],
    future_values=batch["future_values"],
    future_time_features=batch["future_time_features"],
)
```